# Unable to install tiktoken from PyPI

Tags: pypi, setup.py, openai-api

I am working on some OpenAI's API integrations. I am facing an issue while installing the tiktoken (a fast BPE tokeniser for use with OpenAI's models).

When I try to run on my macbook machine:

`pip3 install tiktoken -v`

It throws the following error (Using pip 22.3.1, error truncated because very long):

```
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /Users/gianlucatrentin/gptenv/bin/python3 -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-install-l7tec_bv/lxml_b78f1cdebea441d2b840e6957fabe83a/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-wheel-sd9x1ng7
  cwd: /private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-install-l7tec_bv/lxml_b78f1cdebea441d2b840e6957fabe83a/
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
  Running command python setup.py clean
  Building lxml version 4.9.2.
  Building without Cython.
  Building against libxml2 2.9.13 and libxslt 1.1.35
  running clean
  removing 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310' (and everything under it)
  removing 'build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310' (and everything under it)
  'build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build/scripts-3.10' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
 ...
  × Running setup.py install for pycryptodomex did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /Users/gianlucatrentin/gptenv/bin/python3 -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-install-l7tec_bv/pycryptodomex_7192f9e9e3b34b15b1960598d9d7eb02/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' install --record /private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-record-n_aypwf1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gianlucatrentin/gptenv/include/site/python3.10/pycryptodomex
  cwd: /private/var/folders/sc/gl1552412gb0lg7_x33zrgj00000gn/T/pip-install-l7tec_bv/pycryptodomex_7192f9e9e3b34b15b1960598d9d7eb02/
  Running setup.py install for pycryptodomex ... error
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycryptodomex

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I try to upgrade all the mentione libraries but couldn't make it work.
Do you have suggestions on how to solve this installing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I Encountered This Problem When I Was Installing tiktoken for My Language Model. I Successfully Installed it by following ways.

First of all Upgrade your pip, and setuptools.

Then install setuptools_rust by

```
pip install setuptools_rust
```

Then Just install libxml2, libxlst by

```
pkg install libxml2, libxslt
```

If Still It Doesn't Work, if You Encounter "Can't Find Rust Compiler" Try Installing Rust by

```
pkg install rust
```

After All These Steps, It Should Be Installed.

Hope it Helps You...

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of these two:

1. Install rust by following the instructions on: https://rustup.rs/

OR (if you cannot install rust)

2. Install tiktoken from wheel file instead of building wheel by yourself.

Comment: "Install tiktoken from wheel file instead of building wheel by yourself." Could you explain how to do this?